# Ошибка Future в pyppeteer

Tags: python, asyncio, puppeteer

```
# https://bot.sannysoft.com/

from pyppeteer import *
from pyppeteer_stealth import stealth
import asyncio

# --------------------------------------------------------------

def handle_price(some_price):
    for element in some_price:
      try:
          int(element)
      except:
          some_price = some_price.replace(element, '')
    return some_price

#-----

async def get_wildberries_price(browser):
  page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/98649739/detail.aspx')
  await page.waitFor('.price-block__final-price')
  raw_price = await page.evaluate('''
  () => {
    return document.querySelector('.price-block__final-price').textContent
  }
  ''')
  final_price = handle_price(raw_price)
  await page.screenshot({'path': 'wildberries.png'})
  return final_price

#-----

async def get_ozon_price(browser):
  page = await browser.newPage()
  await stealth(page)
  await page.goto('https://www.ozon.ru/product/setka-sadovaya-plastikovaya-0-61-sm-opornaya-dlya-rasteniy-rulon-5-m-yacheyka-7-10-mm-zelenaya-746399567/?advert=LMWD3jhEugrU0NaiTNSLwpAIIbCdFMNn7pzKseZ54oiYJzffMkWL5dFUOvP2QxFxTe6r-62ds5iYdNtmm39GeVmWNx7Drk2RfA-NFruujb9wW_wbefQotjVI3Nw6nmw-7bz9eBuQf1jcWO9oKG03ATRZlVPYDWDUpt-Vr6TP01QKzNpkDGeyKNFDYr0mQ6zHtTc2xumWB3-dv2Gz-N1MubGGYv1HNBGFFtjS2sjma9sLgVekajUUaWojBH262l4QrAW1M9rCl-81e2UuCuA6e9e30jQi6V5VQGajDtoh7hlSqVBeuWTgQwBh93dIZprdLVVLO8wjhyroY4zH5kCXsPosmppupEfHuVI3WyxszZDRKZaftEvaKMKR1BDr1rtJDPW_pNvM1ZhWuCyJp9hsDQsED8fQ3RFRWR8LNZ5WYr8h_sjfYw1xlrl5-rjcS2MaBuBeYL3GQ4pXFwrkRKOEFuLsDScNPdIL2rDN9aeFT_lW5QnmTG_L177BU5QyZM2DLu7pN8H3K0To7QDSzvLpfVqCHWaudAT54N6mTU8GAtwBLp6sWpQNKDwnqqFLxmdC1s-3-U2t3h6jwkvEH5nue2hZdmrdu4Z-eD2qbnblV340tMRQZ3V8vcw-QO0BiDqNQupojM-i61GULUdv8a8qa12Uir-HZ1OOaKekgidc-IKoCUbTCa8YfpV5zXASOBlxvqs84FoG8vEg2yNkN4fRSOOkfcSp29rssttskpEkp14dZ3o_XnJ93SI1SR13ffRmFMGVZiwDjOyHjovEELGadA&avtc=1&avte=2&avts=1674570447&keywords=%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2&sh=6RhLQaLOhA')
  await page.waitFor('[slot="content"] span')
  raw_price = await page.evaluate('''
  () => {
    return document.querySelector('[slot="content"] span').textContent
  }
  ''')
  final_price = handle_price(raw_price)
  await page.screenshot({'path': 'ozon.png'})
  return final_price

# --------------------------------------------------------------

async def main():
  main_browser = await launch({
    # 'headless': False,
  })
  
  print(await get_wildberries_price(main_browser))
  print(await get_ozon_price(main_browser))

  await main_browser.close()

main_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
main_loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Ошибка:

```
(Future exception was never retrieved
future:<Future finished exception=NetworkError('Protocol error Target.sendMessageToTarget: Target closed.')>
pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol error Target.sendMessageToTarget: Target closed.)
```

Появляется не часто (где-то раз в 4 запуска)

Причём я заметил что если переставить местами
`print(await get_wildberries_price(main_browser))`
и
`print(await get_ozon_price(main_browser))`
то код будет работать исправно.

Не понимаю почему очерёдность перехода на сайт имеет значение

Прошу ПОМОГИТЕ, ничего не получается

Answer (score 0):

После проверка через отладчик, выявилось что проблема была в функции screenshot. После её удаления всё работает как по маслу. Если знаете почему так напишите.